# Как копировать файл по ssh

Tags: ssh

Как скопировать файл по ssh находясь уже на сервере?

я подключился по ssh (ssh somename@somespost)

как мне теперь копировать файл с локального компьютера в директорию в которой я сейчас нахожусь?

или может нужна какая-нибудь утилита?

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_copying.htm

Comment: `cp configuration.php-dist configuration.php`

Comment: так не роботает

Comment: мануал прочитай, это пример из мануала

Comment: *уже на сервере?* — **по умолчанию** — никак. такую дыру в безопасности разработчики протокола ssh (первая буква — от слова «secure») не могли себе позволить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть утилита scp

Пользоваться ей так:

```
scp сервер1:/путькфайлу ~/путьназначения
```

Пример

```
scp root@servername.com:/tmp/1.sql ~/Downloads/1.sql
```

Файл окажется на Вашем компьютере в домашней директории папочке Downloads

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php):

```
scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost:/some/remote/directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Так вряд ли получится, потому что у вашего локально компьютера не белый IP. Но получится, находясь на локальном, копировать на сервер.

### Если локальный компьютер под Linux

Использовать [scp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP)

```
scp имя_файла_на_локальном_компьютере имя_пользователя_на_сервере@ip_сервера:/путь_до_папки_на_сервере
```

например

```
scp readme.txt user@192.168.0.1:/home/user/temp
```

будет копировать файл readme.txt с локального компьютера на сервер в папку Temp домашней директории пользователя user

### Если локальный компьютер под Windows

Использовать [winscp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) Это приложение с интерфейсом на два окна. В одном будет ваш локальный компьютер, во втором удаленный сервер.