# Сервис VDSINA, пытаюсь поставить python файл на VDS, поставил ос ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, vds

Сервис VDSINA, пытаюсь поставить python файл на VDS, поставил ос ubuntu, как поставить это всё далее не знаю, пожалуйста объясните мне это более подробно.. = (

Comment: Python уже изначально предустановлен в Ubuntu

Comment: мне нужно установить именно мой код на этот хостинг..

Comment: Никто кроме *вас* не может знать, как правильно устанавливать *ваш* код

Comment: Обычный код на python, проблема в том, как мне перекинуть на ubuntu по ssh? Вот это проблема.

Comment: Значит так и нужно было сформулировать вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731958

Comment: А можно пожалуйста какие-то подробности, потому что я нашёл про это, но вот как мне указать путь с моего пк допустим? C:\Users\Skan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\requests_parser.py - файл тут, а на убунту я вообще не знаю директории и т.д

Comment: Кажется, вам лучше сперва почитать какую-нибудь книжку по основам линукса

Comment: Far, Alt+F2, Netbox, Shift+F4, заполнить IP/login/password, сохранить подключение, после подключится, выбрать нужный каталог на удаленном сервере (/home/... например). После Alt+F1, выбрать нужный каталог на своем ПК, выбрать файл который нужно скопировать на сервер, нажать F5.